# Stripe account capabilities set but still throws an error

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I did create Stripe Account using the following parameters:

```
stripe.accounts.create({
  type: 'custom',
  business_type: 'individual',
  individual: {
      email: user.email,
      first_name: user.firstName,
      last_name: user.lastName
  },
  requested_capabilities: ['card_payments', 'transfers'],
  email: user.email,
  tos_acceptance: {
    date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
    ip: user.ip
  }
})
```

But if I am trying to create transfer, I get the following error:

> Your destination account needs to have at least one of the following
> capabilities enabled: transfers, legacy_payments

This is how I create the transfer:

```
stripe.transfers.create({amount, currency, destination, transfer_group})
```

It seems weird because the required capabilities are set as you can see. I do not know how to debug further. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the 'transfers' capability active? You've requested it, but there might still be verification requirements required before it is enabled for the account and you can make transfers. The `requirements` hash on the object should say what is needed : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#determining-if-identity-or-business-verification-is-needed

Answer (score 7):

The reason the transfer is failing is that onboarding is not complete - there are requirements for the "transfer" capability to be enabled. When creating the account you have only "requested" the correct capabilities but they are not yet granted.

Simply fetch the account based on the id and see what fields are are required and provide them - either on your end by updating the account through the API or in the Stripe web admin if you only want to quickly provide everything so you can test. (The stripe web admin has all the fields required for full onboarding of an account)

Once the transfers capability requirements are fulfilled, it will be granted and it will turn green. After that transfers will be allowed. (Similar thing goes for the "card payments" capability. Regarding the "legacy" capability you should not use that anymore since it will become 
 deprecated in March 31 2020)

(you might even need to supply an external bank account, you can [get that here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing))

Comment: Thanks for explaining the verification part. But can u tell me if my customer who is receiving money is individual then why he/she has to enter the industry information? Am I allowed to put my own there as prefilled?

Comment: The requirements list is quite dynamic and differs a lot based on a number of factors - like type of account(business, individual, organization etc), which country it's in, etc. When you load an account the requirement fields will tell you exactly what they still need in order to be fully verified. Their mentality is that they request verification information gradually as you reach certain limits so in the response they give you required now, required soon fields etc. (you can supply most of them at the beginning if you like) More info: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api

Comment: I recommend you use their testing platform and there you can put whatever you like and it should accept it. (maybe needs to be well formatted but doesn't need to be real data) When I test I use custom connect accounts with organization number "1234567". But even as type "individual" there are still required verification fields to enable transfers.

Comment: I used test verification data when you go into doc upload stripe offers you to use test docs, and worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i added this code
if you are using python:

```
stripe.Account.modify(
               "acct_1JKoh0PpggScpyQX", //this is the account id
                tos_acceptance={
                    'date': int(time.time()), //import time
                    'ip': '8.8.8.8', // Depends on what web framework you're using
                }
            )
```

else other language
check this link https://stripe.com/docs/connect/updating-accounts#tos-acceptance

this code indicate to Stripe that a connected account accepted the Stripe Connected Account Agreement.