# Stripe, Send money to Customer

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I am making an app like Uber. I want to pay employees every start of week. but i don't have any idea about it. Every week the system will calculate and pay the driver's salary.
With the Bank information submitted by the customer, I transferred money from the customer to the admin, but I don't know how to pay the driver's salary.o the customer.
This my code

```
// account test
            $bank = $stripe->tokens->create([
                'bank_account' => [
                    'country' => 'US',
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'account_holder_name' => 'Jenny Rosen',
                    'account_holder_type' => 'individual',
                    'routing_number' => '110000000',
                    'account_number' => '000123456789',
                ],
            ]);

            // create account
            $account = \Stripe\Account::create(
                array(
                    "country" => "US",
                    'type' => 'custom',
                    'capabilities' => [
                              'card_payments' => [
                                'requested' => true,
                              ],
                              'transfers' => [
                                'requested' => true,
                              ],
                            ], 
                    'external_account' => $bank->id
                )
            );

            $re = $stripe->transfers->create([
                'amount' => 400,
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'destination' => $account->id,
                'transfer_group' => 'ORDER_95',
              ]);
        
              return $re;
```

Error response:

```
 "Your destination account needs to have at least one of the following capabilities enabled: transfers, legacy_payments".
```

How to pay employee via Stripe. Please help me !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stripe account capabilities set but still throws an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60336861/stripe-account-capabilities-set-but-still-throws-an-error)

Comment: You have to actually onboard the account by providing the legally required KYC info. All that code does is create the account and try to send cash to it. You have to onboard the account(https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connect-onboarding) first (there's test info to use at https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#identity-and-address-verification-) and when that's done, the capability is active and you can try to make a transfer!